# TeX Live font policy

Tags: fonts, texlive

I would like to request inclusion of these fonts to TeX Live (only *.mf files are needed):

> CTAN: tex-archive/fonts/cyrillic/scyrillic

I negotiated this with the author and he agreed to cooperate.

Now it is necessary to find out what criteria a font package must fulfill to be eligible for inclusion in TeX Live. Is it sufficient to put only LICENSE file to the archive? Is there any example of the simplest LICENSE file?

What is the procedure of requesing TeX Live team to add this font package?

Are there TeX Live's own recommendations on this subject?

*Note:* I'm not asking which license should be applied, etc.

Comment: If you're not asking which license should be applied, why do you ask for the simplest LICENSE file? I can't tell what you're really asking here. You've probably already seen it, but what might be considered minimal requirements are here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/copying.html

Comment: @PaulGessler I'm asking the advice of people who have experience with similar issue - on the whole, not about these specific fonts, because I know that "lawyer" advises are avoided on this forum.

Comment: I would like to vote to re-open, but the question is still poorly worded. Are you asking what the procedure is to upload a set of fonts to CTAN? TeX Live will take from CTAN what is appropriate, but that's a separate matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As boring as it may sound, I think you should just send an email to the TeX Live list (`tex-live@tug.org`, see [the list’s page](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live) for more information) to make sure the developers are aware of the fonts and are going to include it in TeX Live.

And you *should* definitely make sure that the fonts are available under some reasonable licence.  If you don’t have any preference, the LPPL seems the best choice for TeX fonts (not my personal preference, but in my opinion the best one for TeX distributions).  You really need to choose a licence, even if you – or the original author – don’t care about it.  Having no licence or some vague wording is ***not acceptable*** and will lead to the package’s exclusion from TeX Live.

Comment: I have sent an email to tex-live@tug.org

Answer (score 2):

To prepare a package for upload to TeXLive, you should look at the following page and the links on it:

[Uploading to CTAN](http://ctan.org/file/help/ctan/CTAN-upload-addendum)

TeXLive, as I understand it, gets its packages from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org), provided that it has an appropriate license.  This also means your package will be available to distributions other than TeXLive.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to suitable licensing, the files have to have non-conflicting names. The files are currently named in ways which conflict with existing components of TeX Live. They would need to be renamed to avoid this.

Note that there is no guarantee the package will be included if it meets the minimum criteria.

Comment: Please be more specific about which packages these fonts conflict with.